# Integrating Windows Explorer's preview pane into WPF app

Tags: wpf, preview-pane

I've looked at a [couple](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/tamir/archive/2008/04/18/using-vista-preview-handlers-in-wpf-application.aspx) of [articles](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/eyal/archive/2007/07/29/Hosting-vista_2F00_office-2007-previewers-in-winform-application.aspx) today, and it doesn't seem to be working, I don't have enough of an idea of what is going on to troubleshoot... any simpler implementations or insights that may make this easier?

Answer (score 0):

A WPF based treeview would exactly solve the purpose. [This](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/WPF_Explorer_Tree.aspx) is a classic example of it's implementation for Windows Explorer.

Comment: I think the OP is looking for how to integrate the _preview pane_ from windows explorer, not the explorer tree.